# having 2 or more navigation controllers embedded on a stack

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

Im trying to get two navigation controller on the same stack, and pass data between them   , the best way to explain this is by the image below .

[image: storyboards]

first nav controller(the one thats furthest to the left ) is connected to a TabBarController .

When passing data from the TEST tableViewController to the 2nd tableViewController (subDuaList) , i get an error in my code in the prepareForSegue method ...

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        var subDua:subDuaList = segue.destinationViewController as subDuaList //ERROR OCCURS HERE

        var Index = tableView!.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row

        var duaIndex = 130 - Index!

        var selectedDua = self.packagedChapter[duaIndex]
        println(selectedDua.title)

        subDua.duaArray = selectedDua.dataArray
        subDua.rowPressed = Index

    }
```

Reason for embedding the second tableViewController in a Navigation controller is so that **I can add a bar button item to the nav bar.**

Comment: I think you don't need to add a second navigation controller to add a UIBarButtonItem to your 'subDuaList'. (I don't know Swift too well, so I will post the code in objective-c) Just remove the second navigation controller from storyboard and write `subDua.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = yourBarButtonItem;` in your `subDuaList` class (or in `prepareForSegue:` method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

As @Shim commented right, my answer just explains the reason for the error output, but does not tell the things **I already said in my comment on your question**:

It is not allowed to push a `UINavigationController` on an existing navigation stack. Therefore you should remove the second navigation controller and just add a `UIBarButtonItem` to the `navigationItem` of your `subDuaList` view controller.

---

The reason for your error is, that the `segue.destinationViewController` is the second `UINavigationController` and not the `subDuaList` view controller.

**If it was allowed, you could have repaired your code as follows** by replacing:

```
var subDua:subDuaList = segue.destinationViewController as subDuaList //ERROR OCCURS HERE
```

with

```
var navCtrl:UINavigationController = segue.destinationViewController as UINavigationController 
var subDua:subDuaList = navCtrl.childViewControllers[0] as subDuaList
```

Comment: Even if you do fix this issue, AFAIK pushing navigation controllers onto an existing navigation stack is not supported (can do it with a modal presentation though, but that's not the same thing), so it will still crash (recently encountered this on an Objective C project, presumably applies in Swift too).

Comment: You are right. That is what I said in my comment under the question above. Should edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a new navigation controller to add a bar button item. You can add a bar button item in the storyboard by dragging it onto the navigation bar (if the view controller is in a navigation stack and you don't see one, check the simulated metrics in the inspector), or you can add it in code like so:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = myBarButtonItem;
```